# Deriving the Key Renewal Theorem from Blackwell's Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, renewal-processes

Let $\{X_n:n=1,2,\ldots\}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with finite mean $\mu$ and assume there exists no $d\geqslant0$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X_1=nd)=1$ (i.e. the renewal process is non-lattice). Define  $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ for positive integers $n$ and $N(t) = \sup\{n: S_n\geqslant t\}$ for $t\geqslant 0$. Let $m(t) = \mathbb  E[N(t)]$ be the renewal function.

Blackwell's Theorem states that for all $a\geqslant 0$,
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} m(t+a)-m(t) = \frac a\mu.
$$

Let $h:[0,\infty]\to\mathbb R$ be a directly Riemann integrable function, that is
$$
\lim_{a\to 0}\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup\{h(t) : (n-1)a\leqslant t\leqslant na\} = \lim_{a\to 0}\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \inf\{h(t) : (n-1)a\leqslant t\leqslant na\}
$$

The Key Renewal Theorem states that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_0^t h(t-x)\ \mathsf dm(x) = \frac1\mu \int_0^\infty h(t)\ \mathsf dt.\tag1
$$

From Blackwell's Theorem we see that
$$
\lim_{a\to 0} \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{m(t+a)-m(t)}a = \frac1\mu.\tag2
$$
Ross's *Stochastic Processes* (p. 112) says:

> Now assuming that we can justify interchanging the limits, we obtain
> $$
> \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{\mathsf dm(t)}{\mathsf dt}= \frac1\mu.\tag3
> $$
> The key renewal theorem is a formalization of the above.

I am not sure how to justify the interchange of limits in $(2)$, but it is clear that, assuming $m$ were differentiable, $(3)$ would be the result. However, it is not at all obvious that $m$ should be differentiable, aside from when the $X_i$ are absolutely continuous. See for example this question: [Convolution form of the renewal density](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665752/convolution-form-of-the-renewal-density)

I also do not see how one arrives at $(1)$ from $(3)$. Here it seems we must interpret e.g. $\mathsf dm(x)$ in the Riemann-Stieltjes sense, but it is not clear where the relation between the (limiting) convolution of $h$ with $\mathsf dm$ and the integral of $h$ over $[0,\infty)$ comes from. How can we show this rigorously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h$ is a step function, then (1) follows readily from (2) via Cesaro summation [On Cesàro convergence: If $ x_n \to x $ then $ z_n = \frac{x_1 + \dots +x_n}{n} \to x $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/on-ces%c3%a0ro-convergence-if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn)

In the general case, approximate $h$ from above and below by step functions, and use the direct integrability assumption to ensure that the two limits you get are arbitrarily close.